# How to create "docked" items in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm looking to create a display similar to the following screenshot:

[image]

The main point is that each list item can be "expanded" to show sub-items. How can I create this in Android? I'm not even sure how to have multiple types of list item renderers, let alone how to accomplish this, but I do know how to generally set up a ListView, its adapter, and the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). It uses a special [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) with different views for children vs. parents. Also at the bottom that is most likely a Footer that has been added to the ListView.